# Why is pressure through my water softener intermittently weak?

Tags: water-softener

I have a Kenmore 625.383560 water softener (WS), and I experienced consistent low water pressure previously. Earlier post is here: [Why does my water softener cause low water pressure?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/258630/why-does-my-water-softener-cause-low-water-pressure)

As advised, I took out the distributor tube and cleaned both top and bottom distributors (and an additional metal mesh screen that sits inside the top distributor). There were a small amount of resin trapped inside the distributor tube, but not much. The slits of the distributor seemed clear. However, the screen seemed clogged with white/clear balls that are JUST the right size to lodge in the mesh. I'm not sure if these balls are resin - they don't look orange and seem much smaller than the typical resin ball.

The resin itself didn't feel slimy. The internet also advised trying to squeeze them between your thumb and finger to see if they break easily. I was able to crush some by grinding it between my fingers, but they certainly didn't just fall apart.

I am getting good pressure again, but only for a few minutes for high-flow faucets like the bath tub and the shower. After about 5 mins the pressure drops way down to 20 psi or less. Occasionally, I get white cloudy water... not sure if this is related.

I think my main pressure regulator is good because I just replaced it a few months ago.

Please, please anyone got a good lead on what to do? (Other than replacing the whole thing because we really can't afford that right now!)

Comment: I will take a SWAG: first you need to determine the source of the contaminate. A relative simple solution would to pre filter the water going into the softner. If that solves the problem the softener is OK, if not you may have to replace the rezein. Be sure those white things are not salt.

Comment: Update after having solved the issue: You were completely right about replacing the resin! In hindsight, the contaminant must have been bits of finely degraded resin!

Answer (score 0):

Happy to share that I solved the issue. It was the resin that went bad. Full answer here: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/262247/157232